# How can I determine The numerator and the power from a certain number?

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

```
8=2^3, 81=3^4.
```

How can I discover or find out which/what number can stand as a numerator and as a power for a certain number for example:

8 is the initial/certain number, but was split to 2 raised to the power of 3 where;

```
2 is the numerator and 3 is the power
```

Is there a software/algorithm of any sort that can provide an answer to this question for example 64?

Comment: This looks like *prime factor decomposition*. You can find more on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization). Essentially no know direct algorithm exists, so a simple way is to use trial divisions from an Eratosthene sieve up to sqrt(n).

Comment: Check this, exact same question: https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/power-of-two-integers/

Comment: @abinhav it doesn't provide any answer of any sort

Comment: @serge i don't understand the alternate option you mentioned

Comment: Answer has already been pointed out by @serge. thankfully there is no such method for a number obtained by the multiplication of two very big prime numbers ... otherwise some cryptographic methods running modern world will be open to hack. Also the question is not clear if the numerator has to be the smallest possible number. A very simple example if the number is 10000, how will you know it is 10^4 or 100^2?

Comment: @amit the answer would have been correct if it were to be prime factor decomposition. Sadly it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by iterating over powers and finding the highest nth root that produces an integer.

```
from math import log
def findPower(N):
    if N == 0: return (0,1)  # support zero
    if N < 0:                # support negatives
        r,p = findPower(-N)
        return (-r,p) if p%2 else (N,1)

    for power in range(int(log(N,2)),1,-1): # int(log(N,2))=N.bit_length()-1
        root = int(N**(1/power))
        for r in range(root-1,root+2):
            if r**power == N: return (r,power)

    return (N,1)

print(findPower(81))               # (3,4)
print(findPower(8))                # (2,3)
print(findPower(371293))           # (13,5)
print(findPower(29**7))            # (29,7)
print(findPower(-232630513987207)) # (-7, 17)
```

*Note that this returns (n,1) for n = -1, 0 or 1 even though they all have an infinite number of solutions.  It also returns only the positive base for even powers.*

**[EDIT]** the above function is limited by the capabilities of floating point number representation.  It will choke on very large integers.

Here is an alternative approach that supports Python's "infinite size" integers, using binary search for nth roots calculations and optimized using prime factors of the resulting exponent.

**integer root calculation**

```
# integer nth root of number X, Returns None if no exact root
rootMod7 = { p:{d**p%7 for d in range(1,8)} for p in range(1,7) }
def intRoot(X,n):
    if n==1 or X==1: return X
    odd,bits  = X&1, X.bit_length()           # odd/even and bit magnitude
    if X%7 not in rootMod7[(n-1)%6+1]: return # mod 7 match possible roots
    lo,hi = 1<<(bits//n),1<<(bits//n+1)       # starting range on log(X,n)
    while lo<=hi:
        root = (lo+hi)//2                     # binary search
        if root&1 != odd: root += root < hi   # odd/even must match X's
        delta = X - root**n
        if delta == 0: return root
        if delta<0 : hi = root - 2  # adjust range
        else:        lo = root + 2  # on odd/even boundaries   
    return None
```

**Prime number generator**

```
def quickPrimes(N):
    isPrime = [False,True]*(N//2+1)
    primes  = [2]
    for p in range(3,N+1,2):
        if not isPrime[p]: continue
        primes.append(p)
        isPrime[p*p:N+1:p] = (False for _ in range(p*p,N+1,p))
    return primes
```

**Solution for huge numbers**

```
# finds base and power where base**power == N    
def basePower(N):
    base,power = (N,1) if N>=0 else basePower(-N)
    if N<1: return (-base,power) if power%2 else (N,1)
    maxPower   = N.bit_length()
    for p in reversed(quickPrimes(maxPower)):
        if p>maxPower: continue
        root = intRoot(base,p)
        while root:  # prime factorisation of exponents
            maxPower = maxPower//p + 1
            base,power = root,power*p 
            root = intRoot(base,p)
    return base,power
```

This version can process huge numbers in a reasonable amount of time.

for example:

```
basePower(1522756**5553) # (1234, 11106) in 46  seconds, 34,333 digits
basePower(12345**12345)  # (12345,12345) in 159 seconds, 50,510 digits
```

**[EDIT2]** A much better solution using prime factorisation:

You can find prime factors and take the greatest common denominator (gcd) of prime counts.

For example 216000's prime factors are 2^6, 3^3, 5^3 so the power will be 3. For each of the primes keep count/3 as the power to compute the base: 2^2 * 3^1 * 5^1 = 60. So 216000 = 60^3

```
def primeFactors(N):   # returns dictionary of {prime:count}
    result = dict()
    p = 2              # p is a candidate prime factor   
    while p*p<=N:      # prime candidates up to √N (remaining N) 
        while N%p == 0:   # count prime factors
            result[p] = result.get(p,0)+1 
            N //= p       # by removing factors, only primes will match
        p += 1 + (p&1)    # next potential prime
    if N>1: result[N] = 1 # anything remaining after √N is a prime
    return result

def gcd(a,b=0,*c):                    # gcd using Euclid's algorithm
    if c: return gcd(gcd(a,b),*c)     # for multiple values
    return a if not b else gcd(b,a%b) # Euclidian division version

def findPower(N):
    counts = primeFactors(N)       # {prime factor: count}
    power  = gcd(*counts.values()) # power is gcd of prime counts
    base   = 1                  
    for f,c in counts.items():     # compute base
        base *= f**(c//power)      # from remaining prime powers
    return base,power
```

This is much faster that the previous large-integer solution:

```
    findPower(12345**12345))     # (12345,12345) in 2.8 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

A prime factor decomposition will give you the expected result. Demo:

```
def erato(n):
    """Search primes up to n using an Eratosthene's sieve"""
    is_prime = [1] * n               # expect all to be primes
    for i in range(2,n):             # and remove any multiple starting with 2
        if is_prime[i] != 0:         #  but ignoring non primes
            for j in range(i*i, n, i):
                is_prime[j] = 0      # a multiple is not prime
    return [i for i in range(2, n) if is_prime[i] != 0]

def decomp(n):
    s = int(math.sqrt(n) + 1.5)      # extract primes list up to sqrt(n)
    primes = erato(s)
    factors = []
    for i in primes:
        if i * i > n:                # stop at sqrt(n)
            break
        q, r = divmod(n, i)
        if r == 0:                   # found a divisor
            p = 1
            n = q
            while True:              # compute the exponent
                q, r = divmod(n, i)
                if r == 0:
                    p += 1
                    n = q
                else:
                    break
            factors.append((i, p))   # store the pair divisor, exponent
    return factors

>>> decomp(8)
[(2, 3)]
>>> decomp(81)
[(3, 4)]
```

Comment: Why a demo? Probably why it doesn't work on my IDE?

Comment: I hoped it could help. If it is not want you want, I shall delete it...

Comment: Please don't delete @serge. But how should i apply the code on my IDE. I couldn't and that's why i'm reaching out for assistance.

Comment: @DaveKent I do not know where the problem can ben. Above code only contains the definition of 2 functions (this part should work without problem by copying the definitions one at a time), and the call of `decomp` twice (this part does contain the `>>> ` prompt and the response)